# Expected a ';' before int main bracket

Tags: c++, game-physics

So I get an error for not putting a ';' before the bracket '{' right after int main and the annoying part is that I've tried anything I could so far (Warning: I am not an experienced coder at all) I even tried to put in new libraries but it wouldn't work. I noticed though that by taking a similar code with the same int main and copy/pasting it, that only the keyboard function was the one creating the problem.... I really cannot understand... Thank you in advance for any help given :)

```
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include <math.h>

class Boxes
{



public: float x;
public: float y;
public: float w;
public: float h;
public: float r;
public: float g;
public: float b;
public: float i;
public: float j;
public: bool ActiveBox;
public: bool Horizontal;


        void Draw()
        {
            glColor3f(r, g, b);
            glRectf(x, y, x + w, y + h);

            glColor3f(1, 1, 1);

            glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);
            glRectf(x, y, x + w, y + h);
            glVertex2f(x, y);
            glVertex2f(x, y + h);
            glVertex2f(x + w, y + h);
            glVertex2f(x + w, y);
            glEnd();
        }

        void Outline(float r, float g, float b, float x, float y, float w, float h)
        {
            glColor3f(r, g, b);
            glRectf(x, y, x + w, y + h);
            glLineWidth(3);
            glColor3f(1, 1, 1);

            glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);
            glVertex2f(x, y);
            glVertex2f(x, y + h);
            glVertex2f(x + w, y + h);
            glVertex2f(x + w, y);
            glEnd();
        }


        Boxes() { x = 0; y = 0; w = 0; h = 0; r = 0; g = 0; b = 0; i = 0; j = 0; ActiveBox = false; Horizontal = false; }
        ~Boxes() { x = 0; y = 0; w = 0; h = 0; r = 0; g = 0; b = 0; i = 0; j = 0; ActiveBox = false; Horizontal = false; }

};


Boxes PuzzlePieces[10];

int grid[6][6];
int d = 1;
int highlight = 1;

void Grid(float i, float j)


{
    for (int i = 1; i < 7; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 1; j < 7; j++)
        {
            grid[i][j];
        }
    }


    grid[1][1] = 1;
    grid[1][2] = 1;
    grid[1][3] = 1;
    grid[1][4] = 1;
    grid[1][5] = 1;
    grid[1][6] = 1;


    grid[2][1] = 1;
    grid[2][2] = 1;
    grid[2][3] = 0;
    grid[2][4] = 1;
    grid[2][5] = 1;
    grid[2][6] = 1;

    grid[3][1] = 0;
    grid[3][2] = 1;
    grid[3][3] = 1;
    grid[3][4] = 1;
    grid[3][5] = 0;
    grid[3][6] = 0;

    grid[4][1] = 1;
    grid[4][2] = 1;
    grid[4][3] = 0;
    grid[4][4] = 1;
    grid[4][5] = 1;
    grid[4][6] = 0;

    grid[5][1] = 0;
    grid[5][2] = 0;
    grid[5][3] = 1;
    grid[5][4] = 1;
    grid[5][5] = 1;
    grid[5][6] = 0;

    grid[6][1] = 0;
    grid[6][2] = 0;
    grid[6][3] = 1;
    grid[6][4] = 0;
    grid[6][5] = 1;
    grid[6][6] = 0;


    PuzzlePieces[1].w = d;
    PuzzlePieces[1].h = 2 * d;
    PuzzlePieces[1].g = 1;


    PuzzlePieces[2].x = 1;
    PuzzlePieces[2].w = d;
    PuzzlePieces[2].h = 2 * d;
    PuzzlePieces[2].g = 1;

    PuzzlePieces[3].x = 2;
    PuzzlePieces[3].w = d;
    PuzzlePieces[3].h = 2 * d;
    PuzzlePieces[3].g = 1;

    PuzzlePieces[4].x = 3;
    PuzzlePieces[4].w = 2 * d;
    PuzzlePieces[4].h = d;
    PuzzlePieces[4].b = 1;
    PuzzlePieces[4].Horizontal = true;

    PuzzlePieces[5].x = 4;
    PuzzlePieces[5].y = 1;
    PuzzlePieces[5].w = 2 * d;
    PuzzlePieces[5].h = d;
    PuzzlePieces[5].b = 1;
    PuzzlePieces[5].Horizontal = true;

    PuzzlePieces[6].x = 1;
    PuzzlePieces[6].y = 3;
    PuzzlePieces[6].h = d;
    PuzzlePieces[6].w = 2 * d;
    PuzzlePieces[6].b = 1;
    PuzzlePieces[6].Horizontal = true;

    PuzzlePieces[7].x = 3;
    PuzzlePieces[7].y = 2;
    PuzzlePieces[7].w = d;
    PuzzlePieces[7].h = 3 * d;
    PuzzlePieces[7].g = 1;

    PuzzlePieces[8].x = 1;
    PuzzlePieces[8].y = 2;
    PuzzlePieces[8].w = 2 * d;
    PuzzlePieces[8].h = d;
    PuzzlePieces[8].r = 1;
    PuzzlePieces[8].Horizontal = true;

    PuzzlePieces[9].x = 2;
    PuzzlePieces[9].y = 4;
    PuzzlePieces[9].w = d;
    PuzzlePieces[9].h = 2 * d;
    PuzzlePieces[9].g = 1;

    PuzzlePieces[10].x = 4;
    PuzzlePieces[10].y = 3;
    PuzzlePieces[10].w = d;
    PuzzlePieces[10].h = 2 * d;
    PuzzlePieces[10].g = 1;

}
   void display(void)
{
    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glLoadIdentity;
    glTranslatef(2.5, 2.5, 0);

    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
    glVertex2f(0, 0);
    glVertex2f(0, 6);
    glVertex2f(6, 6);
    glVertex2f(6, 0);
    glEnd();

    for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++)
    {
        PuzzlePieces[i].Draw();
        if (PuzzlePieces[i].ActiveBox == true)
        {
            PuzzlePieces[i].Outline;
        }
    }

    glColor3f(1, 1, 1);

    glLineWidth(3);
    glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);
    glVertex2f(0, 0);
    glVertex2f(0, 6);
    glVertex2f(6, 6);
    glVertex2f(6, 0);

    glEnd();

    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        PuzzlePieces[i].Draw;
    }



    glFlush();
}

void reshape (int w, int h)
{
    float dx=600, dy=600;
    glViewport (0, 0, (GLsizei) w, (GLsizei) h); 
    glMatrixMode (GL_PROJECTION);
    glOrtho(0.0, dx, 0.0, dy, 0, 10);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
}

void keyboard(unsigned char key, int x, int y)
{
    switch (key) {
    case 27:  exit(0);     // escape ends the programm
    case 'w':
        if (highlight == 0)
        {
            PuzzlePieces[highlight].Outline = true;
        }
        if (highlight != 0)
        {
            PuzzlePieces[highlight].Outline = true;
            PuzzlePieces[highlight - 1].Outline = false;
        }
        if (highlight == 8)
        {
            PuzzlePieces[0].Outline = true;
            highlight = 0;
        }
        highlight++;
        break;

        glutPostRedisplay();

    }

   int main(int argc, char** argv)

**{**
   glutInit(&argc, argv);
   glutInitDisplayMode (GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB);
   glutInitWindowSize (500, 500); 
   glutInitWindowPosition (100, 100);
   glutCreateWindow ("DPSD - Graphics Arm Ex - 4");
   Grid();
   glutDisplayFunc(display); 
   glutReshapeFunc(reshape);
   glutKeyboardFunc(keyboard);
   glutMainLoop();
   return 0;
```

}

Comment: I think you should instead add a `}` *before* ìnt main`.

Comment: You a missing the closing bracket for 'keyboard()`, you have one for the switch inside it, but you don't have one for the function itself.

Comment: What is this `**{**` after main?? Voting to close.

Comment: Yup, missing `}`. If you had indented your code properly, you would notice that instantly.

Comment: 1001 reasons to format your correctly .... #1 you get all the braces you need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
void keyboard(unsigned char key, int x, int y)
{
switch (key) {
case 27:  exit(0);     // escape ends the programm
case 'w':
    if (highlight == 0)
    {
        PuzzlePieces[highlight].Outline = true;
    }
    if (highlight != 0)
    {
        PuzzlePieces[highlight].Outline = true;
        PuzzlePieces[highlight - 1].Outline = false;
    }
    if (highlight == 8)
    {
        PuzzlePieces[0].Outline = true;
        highlight = 0;
    }
    highlight++;
    break;

    glutPostRedisplay();

    }
} // <= This is what you need.

int main(int argc, char** argv)
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! Not even my teacher could find it for Christs' sake